# Proving an isomorphism $T_1T_2$ knowing $T_1$ and $T_2$ are 1-1 and onto, respectively

Tags: linear-algebra

Say V is a finite dimensional vector space, and $T_1: V \to\ V$ and $T_2: V \to\ V$ are linear transformations. Assume that $T_1$ is one to one and $T_2$ is onto.

I am uncertain if my proof that $T_1T_2$ is an isomorphism is valid.

If you don't want to look at the picture - **Is it necessary to show that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are each isomorphisms themselves by Rank-Nullity?**

Here is an image of my work:
[image: Math proof]

Comment: (In case anyone is wondering, this is optional, extra review for a class. The proof is definitely not formal.)

Comment: The kernal of $T_1$ is $\{{\bf 0}\}$. So if $T_1(T_2(v))=\bf0$, you can deduce $T_2(v)=\bf 0$. But how do you surmise $v=\bf 0$? I think the best approach would be to show both $T_1$ and $T_2$ are isomorphisms. Then show the composition is.

Comment: I see how $T_2(v) = 0$ if the composition = 0, but I don't follow the "then show the composition is [an isomorphism]"...

Comment: Sorry, the last two sentences in my previous comment were a different topic...  I meant to suggest that you just redo the whole proof (what you have in the image doesn't seem complete to me). First show that both $T_1$ and $T_2$ are isomorphisms (you just need to show $T_1$ is onto and $T_2$ is one-to-one). Then show $T_1T_2$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I understand how to show $T_1$ is onto and $T_2$ is one-to-one, but afterward, I don't see how I would use that to show $T_1T_2$ is an isomorphism (that's where I get stuck).

Comment: One-to-one: Assume $T_1T_2v=0$. Then since $T_1$ is one-to-one, we must have $T_2v=0$. But $T_2$ is one-to-one; so, $v=0$. It follows that the kernal of $T_1T_2=\{0\}$.$$ $$Onto: use Rank-Nullity (or you can argue directly using the fact that both $T_1$ and $T_2$ are onto).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6750/discussion-between-dmonopoly-and-david-mitra)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is easier to show the following easy claim which follows at once from the dimension (or rank-nullity, if we talk matrices language) theorem:

**Claim:** An operator $\,T:V\to V\,$ , with $\,\dim V<\infty\,$ is bijective iff it is injective iff it is surjective.

With the above, it follows at once that both $\,T_1,T_2\,$ are bijections (isomorphisms of vector spaces)...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a discussion with @David_Mitra, I have an answer that I understand. In short, my picture answer is not sufficient, and I *do* need to show that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are each isomorphisms.

More specifically, we just need to make sure that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are each *one-to-one*:

1. By Rank-Nullity, we can show that $T_2$ is not only onto, but also 1-1.
2. Observe $T_2(v) = 0$ if $T_1(T_2(v))=0$ because $Ker(T_1) = {0} $ (because $T_1$ is 1-1)
3. Observe $v = 0$ if $T_2(v)=0$ because $Ker(T_2) = {0} $ (because $T_2$ is 1-1)
4. Therefore, $Ker(T_1T_2)=Ker(T_1(T_2(v)))=0$ - so $T_1T_2$ is 1-1
5. By Rank-Nullity, we can show that $T_1T_2$ is onto
6. $T_1T_2$ is an isomorphism!